# SQlite3 isn't displaying at end of code PYTHON

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
createDb = sqlite3.connect("hhh.db")
queryCurs = createDb.cursor()

def createTable():
    queryCurs.execute(''' CREATE TABLE maths
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userName TEXT, score INTERGER)''')

def addCust(userName,):
    queryCurs.execute("""INSERT INTO maths (userName, score)
    VALUES(?,?)""",(userName, score))

def main():
    createTable()
    addCust("\n, They scored TEXT, score ITERGER, out of 10 TEXT")
    createDb.commit()

    queryCurs.execute("SELECT * FROM maths")

    for i in queryCurs:
      print ("\n")
      for j in i:
          print (j)

queryCurs.close()
```

It does not display the information that i input into the table.
The code just simply ends without printing the Database information.

Im am a novice so please explain fully

Comment: So where do you actually call `main()` here?

Comment: And where is `score` going to come from in `addCust()`?

Comment: Main is called below Its not included, Im now getting an Error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jacks PC\Desktop\CompletedFinal.py", line 71, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__":main()
  File "C:\Users\Jacks PC\Desktop\CompletedFinal.py", line 58, in main
    createTable()
  File "C:\Users\Jacks PC\Desktop\CompletedFinal.py", line 51, in createTable
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userName TEXT, score INTERGER)''')
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor.

Comment: Well, you did close the cursor in the code you posted. Why not open a cursor each time you need to use one, in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work ? I have moved the creation of the cursor into the main method. In your implementation there is a chance that the cursor is closed before main is executed depending on the location of your main() method.

```
def createTable():
    queryCurs.execute(''' CREATE TABLE maths
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userName TEXT, score INTERGER)''')

def addCust(userName,):
    queryCurs.execute("""INSERT INTO maths (userName, score)
    VALUES(?,?)""",(userName, score))

def main():
    createTable()

    createDb = sqlite3.connect("hhh.db")
    queryCurs = createDb.cursor()

    addCust("\n, They scored TEXT, score ITERGER, out of 10 TEXT")
    createDb.commit()

    queryCurs.execute("SELECT * FROM maths")

    for i in queryCurs:
      print ("\n")
      for j in i:
          print (j)

    queryCurs.close()
```